# JSP,HTML and Javascript - Passing calculation to jsp

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I need to make a simple car loan calculation using html, and pass the all the information to another jsp page. The problem is, I don't know how to pass my javascript calculation method into a form, in jsp. Any ideas or recommendation would be very appreciated! Also, did I make my if else statement correctly? I'm new to jsp so please excuse if I'm too clueless. :)

This is my HTML code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Car Loan Calculation</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <style>
        label {
            text-align:left;
            width:130px;
            display:inline-block;
            padding-top:10px;
        }
        </style>
  </head>
  <body>
        <h1>Perform Car Loan Calculation</h1>
            <form id ="memberFrm" action="processCalculateCarLoan.jsp" method="post" onsubmit="return calculate()">
                            <fieldset>
                                    <legend>Member Registration</legend><br>

                                    <label for="loan">Loan Amount*</label>
                                    <input type="text" id="loan" name="my_loan" size ="15" placeholder="Amount" />
                                    <br/> </br>

                                    <label>Period</label>
                                    <select id="period" name="my_period">
                                       <option value="1">3 years</option>
                                       <option value="2">4 years</option>
                                       <option value="3">5 years</option>
                                       <option value="4">7 years</option>
                                    </select>
                                    <br/> </br>

                                    <p> <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit"/>
                                        <input type="reset" id="btnCancel" value="Cancel"/>
                                    </p>
                            </fieldset>

            </form>
        <script>
            function calculate(){
                var e = document.getElementById("period");
                var years = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
                var loans = document.getElementById("loan").value;
                var calc= document.getElementById("ans");

                if (years === "1"){
                    var total = ((0.28 * 3)+loans);
                }
                else if (years === "2" ){
                    var total = ((0.28 * 4)+loans);
                }
                else if (years === "3" ){
                    var total = ((0.28 * 5)+loans);
                }
                else if (years === "4" ){
                    var total = ((0.28 * 7)+loans);
                }


            }
        </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

This is my JSP code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Car Loan Calculation</h1>
                <fieldset>
                            <%
                                String myLoan = null;
                                String myPeriod = null;


                                myLoan = request.getParameter("my_loan");
                                myPeriod = request.getParameter("my_period");
                            %>

                            <p>Thank you for registering in this event!</p>
                            <p>This is your details;</p>
                            <p>Loan Amount : <%=myLoan%></p>
                            <p>Loan Period : <%=myPeriod%></p>
                            <p>Loan Total : <%=%></p> <!-- I need to display the total calculation here but I don't know how to pass the value. Any ideas?-->


                </fieldset>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The data collected in the HTML page ie; *period* and *loan* should be passed on to the JSP page and do the loan calculation logic in the JSP page and then display it there. This keeps the business logic (*loan calculation*) separated from end user.